# Cleaning data in a column using SQL

Tags: mysql, data-cleaning

I have a column titled "Keywords" that has the keywords associated with each article that is in my dataset. I wrote a query to group the articles according to their keyword so I can make a simple visualization showing which keyword is used the most. The issue is, some of the articles have a secondary keywords, and I need to write a query to filter out those secondary keywords so that just the main one remains. For instance, the "Keywords" column looks like this:

KEYWORDS

1. Policy/Ethics
2. Policy/Ethics
3. Policy/Ethics: Employment
4. Policy/Ethics
5. Policy/Ethics: Business

I need help writing a query that would keep the main keywords (Policy/Ethics), but get rid of the secondary ones. I think I use CASE for this, but I'm not sure or where to begin. Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: a separate column for the secondary keyword would be better

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to split the string on `:` characters and return the first item.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(keywords, ':', 1) AS clean_keywords
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: (cleaner_keywords)